# Submit Button Value does not show full string when there is a space in the string and PHP is used create the button's value

Tags: php

When I use php to create a button's value and the value is a two word string, only the first word is displayed on the button.

Both of the below buttons should show "Compare All" but instead the first one only displays "Compare" on the button.

(Note: I do need to use php for this conditional button value. this is just a simplified version of more complex code for clarity.)

```
<?php
$ButtonDisp = 'Compare All'; //The two words that should appear on first button
?>
<input name="comp_homes" type="submit" value=<?php echo $ButtonDisp ; ?> // only the first word appear>
<br />
<input name="comp_homes" type="submit" value="Compare All"> <!--This works/shows two words-->
```

Comment: put double quotes `value="<?php echo $ButtonDisp;?>"`  [This code works](http://ideone.com/6o4u1) . How's the original now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing quotation marks around the value:

```
<input name="comp_homes" type="submit" value="<?php echo $ButtonDisp ; ?>">
```

Comment: If you checked your HTML output in a browser, you would have seen this.

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't quote it:

```
<input name="comp_homes" type="submit" value="<?php echo $ButtonDisp ; ?>" />
```